# C# UWP лучший подход к хранению и отображению данных в БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Проект C# UWP Windows 10.

Приложение синхронизируется с сервером, получает 14 таблиц (9 из них практически статичные +-200 строк, еще 4 очень часто изменяются но в них примерно 20-100 строк и одна которая изменяется постоянно, как пользователем так и сервером, в ней 1000+ строк).

Приложение должно выводить список из основной (самой большой таблицы), большинство данных в ней ссылки на другие таблицы, само собой при отображении нужно выводить информацию из них.

Сейчас я использую SQLite, сохраняю каждую таблицу, а при сохранении основной добавляю к ней нагрузочную информацию из других таблиц которая необходима при отображении, затем в модели просто загружаю в память (`ObservableCollection`) всю таблицу и цепляю ее к `ListView`. Минусы подхода в том что:

1. Синхронизация на телефоне длится очень долго (минут 5-10 при 2800
   строк в основной таблице).
2. При изменении записей в связанных таблицах приходится перезаписывать всю нагрузочную информацию в основной (что так же очень долго)

Вопрос в том правильно ли я поступаю, или лучше подтягивать поля из нагрузочных таблиц через `get { }`? Как это скажется на производительности?

Или возможно есть более правильные и быстрые способы реализовать подобное?

Comment: А профилировать пробовали? 5 минут звучит слишком дико.

Comment: @Monk Нет не пробовал. Ну на ПК это не больше 30 секнд, а телефон конечно загибается. И это действительно дико... ((

Comment: Не бывает «наилучшего подхода». Пробуйте. То, что подходит в одном случае, будет не подходить в другом.

Comment: @VladD Я с вами согласен, но хотелось бы узнать мнение, некоторые подходы настолько убыточны что даже пробовать не стоит...

Comment: @SYL: Например, если база данных будет расти, то перегонять всю базу клиенту перестаёт иметь смысл. Скорее будет просто выполнять запрос на сервере и отсылать клиенту результаты.

Comment: @VladD ну вся база и не гоняется постоянно. Первый раз она береться полностью а потом в две стороны бегают изменения. Но первая синхронизация 10 минут это очень жестко

Comment: @SYL: Это сейчас база маленькая. А прикиньте, что будет, если потом будет размер в несколько гигабайт.

Comment: если изначальные таблицы отражают разные сущности, то, безусловно, нужно хранить в разных таблицах и join'ить их при запросах. Что используете поверх SQLite? 5-10 минут - явно что-то не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, у Вас отображается список только из основной таблицы, а на при нажатии на элемент начинают показываться данные из кучи других.

Если так, то можно уже немного оптимизировать:

1. Для списка загружаем только основную таблицу (не больше). И создаем метод `Task<Details> LoadDetails()`, который загрузит остальное.
2. Необходимо проверить, что быстрее: загрузить сразу всю основную таблицу или выполнить операцию count(*) + загрузить только первые N строк. Если второе быстрее (теоретически, при малых N, загрузка должна быть мгновенная), то:

   1. Делим весь список на пачки по N элементов, создаем большой список из заглушек.
   2. Если пользователь смотрит элемент из пачки M, то заставляем прогрузиться элементы из пачек M-1, M, M+1. Таким образом, при плавном прокручивании, создается эффект, что всё загружено.
   3. Вся подгрузка идет только в фоновом потоке. UI и так занят делом.
   4. Вместо ObservableCollection используем просто List объектов, каждый из которых имеет свойство Target и Id (позиция в листе). Если null, то показываем "загрузка", если нет - то показываем элемент. Если Target показался - то вызываем функцию, которая спровоцирует загрузку пачки, где будет наш элемент (см. свойство Id). И не забываем про INotifyPropertyChanged.
3. Если пользователь таки нажал на элемент, то показываем заглушку "loading", спешно делаем join по базе и загружаем остальные данные.

Минусы, по сравнению с текущим решением:

1. Детали показываются с запаздыванием
2. У пользователя таки есть шанс заметить недозагруженность, если он будет быстро прокручивать и т.д.

Плюсы, по сравнению с текущим решением:

1. Передается меньше данных для холодного старта.
2. Для списка передается меньше данных, он прогружается быстрее.
3. Визуально для пользователя всегда всё загружено (из-за небольших предзагрузок)

Comment: Да во время работы отображается список только из основной таблицы. `List` специально заменил на `ObservableCollection` т.к. при добавлении новых записей перегружать весь список накладно, просто добавляю его в список (в необходимую позицию) и дальше само собой `INotifyCollectionChanged` делает свое дело. 2я проблема в том что на этапе синхронизации (При записи данных в основную таблицу) записи нужно дополнить нагрузочной информацией из других таблиц (что бы во время работы использовать только одну таблицу).